# Using Pick to set return type of function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface `Foo`

```
interface Foo {
    a: string,
    b: boolean | null,
    c: number
}
```

and an interface `Bar`

```
interface Bar {
    id: number
    value: boolean,
}
```

Now I want to write a function that returns `b` of `Foo`.

```
const aFunction = (barissimo: Bar | null):Pick<Foo, 'b'> {
    if(barissimo) return barissimo.value;
    return null;
}
```

However, this highlights `return barissimo.value`

> Type 'boolean' has no properties in common with type 'Pick '.

and `return null`

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Pick '.

Is it not possible to `Pick` the return type of a function from an existing interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use `Pick` here but [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) :

```
const aFunction = (barissimo: Bar | null):Foo['b'] => {
    if(barissimo) return barissimo.value;
    return null;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJwBcyAzmFKAOYA0%20hARqY5gDYRwjIA%20yIAVzZt6hZAlKCAto2i4AvrlyhIsRCgBCcKDgYFgAE0kCZcsQDc4bARBbtOIeotwJ0ICkVQCQCMMDfIALzIABSM2sBkZMBS6KRaOnyCwgCUxBjoANoA5IzZALpBAHy6YsAwYRFRMegpyFAQYAJQ3OFU1bEAdJbWEADcevWNzdzJbAOKQA)

Comment: Why not `Pick`?

Comment: Pick pulls out the key/value pair(s) you specify, not their types, so `Pick<Foo, 'b'>` is equivalent to `{ b: boolean | null }`, not `boolean | null`.